# Install wordpress in the /web directory inside a Symfony2

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I uploaded the Wordpress files (alogin with its own .htaccess) inside a /web directory that belongs to a Symfony2 installation.

A domain is pointing to that Symfony2. Another domain is pointing to the wordpress directory.

The problem is that the **Symfony2 .htaccess** doesn't allow the Wordpress website to work properly, **not allowing the index.php file to get loaded**.

How should the .htaccess be modified in order to accept both websites in the **same hosting**?

Comment: did you face any issues with indexing WordPress from inside the web folder?

Answer (score 1):

It was solved by adding the following line in the wordpress `.htaccess`

`RewriteOptions inherit`

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to exclude web directory inside symphony htaccess like,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
```

Comment: sadly, it has no effect and keeps showing the 500 internal server error